# How can I find matching elements and indices from two arrays?

Tags: python, match, intersection, indices, idl

For example,

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 100]
b = [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 100]
```

I can find the matching elements using:

```
np.intersect1d(a,b)
```

Output:

```
array([  1,   2,   4,   5,   7, 100])
```

Then, how can I get the indices of matched elements in arrays `a` and `b`, respectively ?

There is a function in IDL as `"match"` - https://www.l3harrisgeospatial.com/docs/match.html

Is there a similar function in Python?

Answer (score 5):

Use `return_indices` in `numpy.intersect1d`:

```
intersect, ind_a, ind_b = np.intersect1d(a,b, return_indices=True)
```

Output:

```
intersect
# array([  1,   2,   4,   5,   7, 100])
ind_a
# array([0, 2, 3, 6, 8, 9], dtype=int64)
ind_b
# array([0, 1, 5, 6, 7, 9], dtype=int64)
```

Which can then be reused like:

```
np.array(a)[ind_a]
np.array(b)[ind_b]

array([  1,   2,   4,   5,   7, 100])
```

Comment: sometimes we just overlook the documentation which gives us everything we need :)

Answer (score 2):

you can track indexes using `enumerate` as follows:

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 100]
b = [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 100]
#    0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8   9

print([i for i,x in enumerate(zip(a,b)) if x[0] == x[1]])
```

```
[0, 2, 5, 6, 9]
```

so what's going on here?!

We're taking advantage of the amazing `enumerate` function! This function generates a tuple for each element in an iterable, with the first element being the enumeration (or the index in this case) and the second being the iterable.

Heres what the enumeration of `zip(a,b)` looks like

```
[(0, (1, 1)), (1, (1, 2)), (2, (2, 2)), (3, (4, 2)), (4, (4, 2)), (5, (4, 4)), (6, (5, 5)), (7, (6, 7)), (8, (7, 8)), (9, (100, 100))]

# lets look a little closer at one element
(0, (1, 1))
# ^     ^
# index iterable
```

From there on it's simple! Unpack the iterable and check if both elements are equal, and if they are then use append the enumeration # to a list!

Answer (score 0):

Use `range` like so:

```
matching_idxs = [idx for idx in range(len(a)) if a[idx] == b[idx]] 
print(matching_idxs)
# [0, 2, 5, 6, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `enumerate` and `zip`:

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 100]
b = [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 100]

output = [(i, x) for i, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(a, b)) if x == y]

print(output)
```

---

```
[(0, 1), (2, 2), (5, 4), (6, 5), (9, 100)]
```

This results in a list of tuples being `(index, value)`

Answer (score 0):

this is very straightforward with the help of `zip` function to loop two lists in parallel:

```py
>>> count = 0
>>> indices = []
>>> for x, y in zip(a, b):
    if x == y:
        indices.append(count)
    count += 1

    
>>> indices
[0, 2, 5, 6, 9]
```